# Graphic Card not recognized

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opencl

I would like to use OpenCL to develop on my computer but my Nvidia graphic card is not recognized by Ubuntu.

What should I do to add it and to be able to use it?

Comment: What is your Nvidia card ?

Comment: First thank you for the anwser. I have a GeForce 705 GT

Answer (score 0):

To install the NVIDIA driver execute:

**Latest version** :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

**Long Term supported version** :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

**For Optimus support:**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

---

You can test both drivers. I currently use version 352 which contains a lot of bug fixes but it can be a little more unstable (I never had a single problem).
Version 346 is a little bit older but long term supported.

Comment: Bumblebleed send me :

[ERROR]No integrated video card found, quitting.